# kernel dies when creating iruby notebook

Tags: sciruby

I am completely noob in SciRuby. For the first time I am using SciRuby. I am following this [video](https://youtu.be/ZxjqsIluM88)  to get an overview of how to use SciRuby and plot graphs, charts etc. When I go to localhost:8888 and I create new notebooks from right drop down(Ruby 2.2.3)

I am in home(~) dir

[image: notebook]

Then at first it says Kernel connecting and then dead kernel message pops up again and again(within gap of few seconds). Nothing happens and the commands I am writing seems to have no effect. Please get this issue solved thanks a lot.

[image: kernel]

```
$ iruby notebook
Could not load bundler: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook`... continue in 5 sec. Press Ctrl-C to quit now.
[I 01:13:51.976 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
[I 01:13:51.976 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 01:13:51.976 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 01:13:51.977 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(firefox:8219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(firefox:8219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(firefox:8219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(firefox:8219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(firefox:8219): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[I 01:14:32.931 NotebookApp] 302 GET / (127.0.0.1) 0.69ms
[I 01:14:39.766 NotebookApp] Creating new file in 
[I 01:14:53.999 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[I 01:14:56.223 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 463b14e0-9f3d-49c0-bd3d-6dd19e7b43d9
W, [2016-03-13T01:14:56.726775 #8272]  WARN -- : Could not load bundler: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:163:in `rescue in root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:159:in `root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:71:in `bundle_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:401:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:57:in `configure'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `definition'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:109:in `check_bundler'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:67:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
You should install rbczmq or ffi_rzmq before running iruby notebook. See README.
F, [2016-03-13T01:14:56.821066 #8272] FATAL -- : Kernel died: uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize': uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
[I 01:14:59.223 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
W, [2016-03-13T01:14:59.619447 #8309]  WARN -- : Could not load bundler: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:163:in `rescue in root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:159:in `root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:71:in `bundle_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:401:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:57:in `configure'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `definition'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:109:in `check_bundler'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:67:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
You should install rbczmq or ffi_rzmq before running iruby notebook. See README.
F, [2016-03-13T01:14:59.696087 #8309] FATAL -- : Kernel died: uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize': uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
[I 01:15:02.231 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
W, [2016-03-13T01:15:02.619460 #8312]  WARN -- : Could not load bundler: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:163:in `rescue in root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:159:in `root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:71:in `bundle_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:401:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:57:in `configure'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `definition'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:109:in `check_bundler'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:67:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
You should install rbczmq or ffi_rzmq before running iruby notebook. See README.
F, [2016-03-13T01:15:02.703792 #8312] FATAL -- : Kernel died: uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize': uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
[I 01:15:05.239 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
W, [2016-03-13T01:15:05.714227 #8316]  WARN -- : Could not load bundler: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:163:in `rescue in root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:159:in `root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:71:in `bundle_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:401:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:57:in `configure'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `definition'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:109:in `check_bundler'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:67:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
You should install rbczmq or ffi_rzmq before running iruby notebook. See README.
F, [2016-03-13T01:15:05.788401 #8316] FATAL -- : Kernel died: uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize': uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
[W 01:15:06.731 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 463b14e0-9f3d-49c0-bd3d-6dd19e7b43d9
[I 01:15:08.247 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 463b14e0-9f3d-49c0-bd3d-6dd19e7b43d9 restarted
W, [2016-03-13T01:15:08.701757 #8318]  WARN -- : Could not load bundler: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:163:in `rescue in root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:159:in `root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:71:in `bundle_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:401:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:57:in `configure'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `definition'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:109:in `check_bundler'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:67:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
You should install rbczmq or ffi_rzmq before running iruby notebook. See README.
F, [2016-03-13T01:15:08.779382 #8318] FATAL -- : Kernel died: uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize': uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
[W 01:15:11.256 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 01:15:11.257 NotebookApp] Kernel 463b14e0-9f3d-49c0-bd3d-6dd19e7b43d9 died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel 463b14e0-9f3d-49c0-bd3d-6dd19e7b43d9 restarted failed!
[W 01:15:11.329 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 01:15:11.330 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/2709e672-f333-42d4-a84b-0c3ab68d3864 (127.0.0.1) 2.11ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=ruby
ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:159:in `root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:71:in `bundle_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:401:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:57:in `configure'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `definition'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:109:in `check_bundler'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:67:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
You should install rbczmq or ffi_rzmq before running iruby notebook. See README.
F, [2016-03-13T01:15:02.703792 #8312] FATAL -- : Kernel died: uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize': uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
[I 01:15:05.239 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
W, [2016-03-13T01:15:05.714227 #8316]  WARN -- : Could not load bundler: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:163:in `rescue in root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:159:in `root'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:71:in `bundle_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:401:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:57:in `configure'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `definition'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:109:in `check_bundler'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:67:in `run_kernel'
/home/abhimanyuaryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/iruby-0.2.8/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/home/abhimanyuarya[I 01:15:53.124 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was Ivan's answer that tipped me off.

In addition to declaring the iruby and nyaplot gems, you need to declare the appropriate ZeroMQ interface.

So, in your Gemfile,

```
gem 'iruby'
gem 'nyaplot'
gem 'rbczmq' # or 'ffi-rzmq'
# any other gems you want to use should go here too
```

Alternatively, if you're working on a project with a gemspec, you need the following two lines in the spec:

```
gem.add_development_dependency 'iruby', '~>0.2'
gem.add_development_dependency 'rbczmq'
```

And also one for nyaplot if that's what you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a file named Gemfile into the folder, which you're using to run iruby, with the following contents:

```
gem 'iruby'
gem 'nyaplot'
# any other gems you want to use should go here too
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. When I create new Ruby 2.2.3 notebook. It creates Untitled.ipynb ......That's related to Python

Comment: Have you installed bundler?

Comment: @SameerDeshmukh yes i typed bundler and its has bond, mimemagic, multi_json, nyaplot, bundler, iruby gems.

Comment: I think you don't have rbczmq installed. One of the lines in the stack trace says so.

Comment: @SameerDeshmukh may be python notebook is creating problem for me? See the second picture I have posted. Its a Firefox web browser screenshot. The link there on top says: `localhost:8888/notebooks/untitled1.ipnyb?kernel_name=ruby`

Answer (score 2):

This method helped me: 
I had installed ruby kernel in jupyter notebook following [SciRuby's GitHub](https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby) page and it worked well that day. But after some days, I again ran it and the kernel started getting dead.
 I don't know the exact reason behind this but I again followed the same method and it installed some extra gems and it worked!! 
Follow this

```
sudo apt install libtool libffi-dev ruby ruby-dev make
sudo apt install libzmq3-dev libczmq-dev
gem install cztop iruby
iruby register --force
```

Run the notebook again

```
jupyter-notebook
```