# iRuby kernel keeps getting killed

Tags: ruby, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, iruby

I am Ruby with Homebrew on macOS Sierra 10.12.3. I installed jupyter with pip install and iruby with gem install

When I run `iruby notebook` the server starts fine but while creating a new notebook Kernel is always killed with following log.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/iruby-0.2.9/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize': uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/iruby-0.2.9/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/iruby-0.2.9/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/iruby-0.2.9/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/iruby-0.2.9/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/iruby:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/iruby:22:in `<main>'
```

I have seen other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999925/kernel-dies-when-creating-iruby-notebook) but there the error message is different.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this particular error came up when running iRuby in a project folder with a Gemfile, and [mentioned in this issue](https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby/issues/74). You may also see a warning when starting iruby to run the register command, as well as add your libraries to the Gemfile.

Add both *iruby* and *ffi-rzmq* in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'iruby'
gem 'ffi-rzmq'
```

then run:

```
$ bundle install
```

After all is installed, go ahead and run iruby again:

```
$ iruby notebook
```

After starting iruby you should see a log without the **uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)** error, and a kernel that does not die.

Even though you may not need to, if for some reason you continue to have issues it may be worth re-registering the kernel after the bundle:

```
$ iruby register --force
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

The [iRuby documentation at github](https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby) suggests using Anaconda and setting your Ruby environment to 2.4.1 using rbenv.  I had the same issue when experimenting with the iRuby kernel.

From the Readme:

> **Mac**
>
> I recommend an installation using Anaconda.
>
> After that, run the following commands.
>
> ```
> brew install rbenv automake gmp libtool wget
> rbenv install 2.4.1
> rbenv global 2.4.1  
> echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
> source ~/.bashrc
> brew install zeromq
> brew install czmq --HEAD
> gem install cztop iruby
> iruby register --force
> ```

Comment: Why not providing the exact code and walkthrough directly inside your answer?

Comment: I wasn't sure what the proper etiquette was.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the kernel is dying but I suspect it has something to do with the zeromq socket interface.  On My Mac I have confirmed the following is working:

Perhaps brew, ruby and python installed a separate zeromq instance.

IRuby 0.2.9
Ruby 2.1.0
Homebrew 1.1.12

I have not had any time to investigate it.